# Do North Korean men have to cut their hair like Kim Jong Un does?

Tags: law, hair, north-korea

I read on several websites that a recent law compels North Korean men to cut their hair like Kim Jong Un does.

Where does this information come from? Is it reliable?

Here is an example in Belgian press: http://www.levif.be/info/actualite/international/la-coree-du-nord-impose-une-unique-coupe-de-cheveux/article-4000571849522.htm (link in french)

Comment: Just found some interesting pieces of information here: http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/03/26/are-the-men-of-north-korea-really-being-forced-to-get-kim-jong-un-haircuts/

Answer (score 4):

The haircut itself is called the 'Dear leader haircut' and is one of a small number of styles men can choose from.

[wantchinatimes.com](http://www.wantchinatimes.com/news-subclass-cnt.aspx?cid=1103&MainCatID=11&id=20130223000071)

> Male university students in North Korea are now required to get the same haircut as their leader Kim Jong-un, it is reported.
>
> The state-sanctioned guideline was introduced in the capital Pyongyang about two weeks ago, [Radio Free Asia reports](http://www.rfa.org/korean/in_focus/hair-03252014095717.html). It is now being rolled out across the country

[BBC News Article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/blogs-news-from-elsewhere-26747649)

Comment: Yes, I saw these ones. The problem is: are they reliable? According to this article ( http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/worldviews/wp/2014/03/26/are-the-men-of-north-korea-really-being-forced-to-get-kim-jong-un-haircuts/ ) maybe not.

Comment: While there are many strange stories from North Korea being relayed without much effort to check the truth, at least some newspapers do their best to debunk many of the myths. http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/apr/24/north-korea-fashion-police